# Override MUI component root node element with styled()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to use the "component" prop with a MUI component (ListItem for example) using the styled() API. My setup below causes an error saying that "component" is not a valid prop. What is the correct way to do this? I can't find any example of this in the docs. Is my only option to use the `sx` syntax?

```
const StyledListItem = styled(ListItem)`
  // some styles here
`;

const MyComponent = () => (
  <StyledListItem component="a" target="_blank" href="#"/>
);
```

Should I use `shouldForwardProps` here?

Answer (score 0):

what you currently have for `component` is not the correct type of value. It needs to be a `elementType` which is actually a component and not a string.

```jsx
<StyledListItem component="a" target="_blank" href="#" />
```

something like this...

```jsx
<StyledListItem component={element} target="_blank" href="#" />
```

Comment: On the ListItem API page in the docs, it says that the component prop can be "Either a string to use a HTML element or a component.", do you have to use an object with the styled() api? What if I want to use an HTML element? When I replace the above code with:

`<StyledListItem component={HTMLAnchorElement} ... />` 

typescript still says that it's not a valid prop

Comment: i copied your code and everything seems to be working for me... are your dependencies updated? [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-mestorf-kzzxh8?file=/src/App.js)